# 2.80 Cycles Render Devices Tab empty

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, system

Just installed the latest release 2.80, July 30 2019, under System the tab Cycles render devices is visible, but empty. So Cycles is not available.

Win10 64, GTX1050ti and onboard GPU, latest drivers.

I tried the installer and the zip-file, same. In 2.80rc is no problem.

What is wrong?

Comment: sorry mixed it 2.80rc got the same problem, 2.80b still running with no problem

Comment: You mean 2.79b, right? There isn't a 2.80b release yet.

Comment: @rjg, Uh, blender 2.80 beta was released a long time ago, and blender 2.80 stable was released in July.

Comment: @Millard a release marked with "b" has nothing to do with beta. It's a patched release. For example there was a 2.79, 2.79a and 2.79b. Alpha, beta and release candidates aren't official releases that get their own version number with letters attached.

Comment: ok, sorry for my lack of knowledge, :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Add-on* and write "device" on search space.

You'll see the option *Render: Cycles Render Engine*. Select this and you will see the options you want!

Comment: No idea how it could have gotten disabled, but this fixed my issue exactly. Thank you! :)